# Include cell value in email body

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, cell

My code is sending an e-mail through Outlook.
I want the value of two cells included in the e-mail body.
Formatting is working and the text is properly shown.
Also the cell value is shown properly in one of two cases.

For one part of the code, it is adding “ACCT:ACCT:ACCT:” in front of the cell value.

The cell value for cell (6,3) = Zeer Dringend
The cell value for cell (22,3) = 2019-0004

This is the e-mail body generated by the code

```
Beste Collega,

Een nieuwe retour zending registratie werd aangemaakt met urgentie: **ACCT:ACCT:ACCT:Zeer Dringend**.

Het pakket nummer is **2019-0004**.


In geval van vragen gelieve contact op te nemen.

Met vriendelijke groeten,
```

Where it shows   **ACCT:ACCT:ACCT:Zeer Dringend**, it should say **Zeer Dringend**

This is the full code

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim WS As Worksheet

If ActiveWorkbook.Path <> "" Then
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Set WS = Sheets("Ingave")

strbody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & _
"Beste Collega,<br><br>" & _
"Een nieuwe retour zending registratie werd aangemaakt met urgentie: <B>" & WS.Cells(6, 3).Value & "</B>.<br>" & _
"Het pakket nummer is <B>" & WS.Cells(22, 3).Value & "</B>.<br><B> " & _
"</B><br><br>In geval van vragen gelieve contact op te nemen." & _
"<br><br> Met vriendelijke groeten, </font>"
On Error Resume Next

With OutMail
.to = "xxx@yyy"
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Nieuwe registratie retour pakket "
.HTMLBody = strbody
.Display   'or use .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Else
MsgBox "U moet de file eerst opslaan voor u verder kan gaan."
End If
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble determining what the issue is here. Is there `ACCT:ACCT:ACCT:Zeer Dringend` in cell(6,3), and you need that trimmed down? If not, can you edit your question with your full code so we can determine where the issue lies?

Comment: This code gives the expected output `"Een nieuwe retour zending registratie werd aangemaakt met urgentie: " & ws.Cells(6, 3).Value & "." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Het pakket nummer is " & ws.Cells(22, 3).Value & "."`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've updated the question with the full code, I hope it is clear now

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided seems to work as expected, you should attempt to investigate where the `ACCT:ACCT:ACCT:` string is actually coming from, maybe the following helps, where I've changed the ActiveWorkbook to ThisWorkbook to eliminate the possibility of the code picking up data from a workbook that might be active, but not necessarily the intended one:

```
Sub Send_Email()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ingave")
'make sure that we are looking at the this workbook and not the Active one.

If ThisWorkbook.Path <> "" Then
'make sure the workbook has been saved, so we get a Path property.

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & _
    "Beste Collega,<br><br>" & _
    "Een nieuwe retour zending registratie werd aangemaakt met urgentie: <B>" & ws.Cells(6, 3).Value & "</B>.<br>" & _
    "Het pakket nummer is <B>" & ws.Cells(22, 3).Value & "</B>.<br><B> " & _
    "</B><br><br>In geval van vragen gelieve contact op te nemen." & _
    "<br><br> Met vriendelijke groeten, </font>"
    'On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .to = "xxx@yyy"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Nieuwe registratie retour pakket "
        .HTMLBody = strbody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    'On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
Else
    MsgBox "U moet de file eerst opslaan voor u verder kan gaan."
End If
End Sub
```